# Double perhaps/or perhaps in the same sentence

Tags: commas, syntactic-analysis

I'm getting tripped up by the rules on when to use a comma for perhaps in a sentence like this:

> Perhaps you have..., or perhaps(,) you know of ...

I understand that the general rule for starting with perhaps is not to use a comma, but when you have it a second time in the sentence does it require a comma? 
I might guess not, because i don,t think it modifies anything, but perhaps you know better? (no comma after this one either i guess)

Comment: Perhaps you haven't considered using two sentences. Or, perhaps, haven't realized that it's usually better to have either no commas at all, or to set off the optional word with commas *before and after it*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mostly no commas around the 2nd "perhaps" these days.

See at Google Books:

[**"Perhaps you have" "or perhaps you"**](https://www.google.ca/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22Perhaps%20you%20have%22%20%22or%20perhaps%20you%22)

e.g.,

> [A Primer of Mathematical Writing: Being a Disquisition on ...](https://books.google.ca/books?id=EYHFObaUIdIC&pg=PA104&dq=%22Perhaps%20you%20have%22%20%22or%20perhaps%20you%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=zgM5Vcz1C5HjsASK_YG4Dw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22Perhaps%20you%20have%22%20%22or%20perhaps%20you%22&f=false) - Page
>   104 Steven George Krantz - 1997
>
> **Perhaps** you have had a fight with the candidate in question and feel
>   that you cannot offer an objective opinion; **perhaps** ... are unfamiliar
>   with the general area in which the candidate works; **or perhaps you** do
>   not know the candidate well at all.